# Author's name does not appear in the bibliography with rusnat style

Tags: natbib

I am quite new to LaTex, so no offense if I don't understand everything :-)

Until now, all references are working perfectly. I use \citep and \bibliographystyle{rusnat}. However, for one reference, LaTex do the compilation, citation in the text is correct, but author's name does not appear in the bibliography.

Here is my bib file:

```
    @article{grimonprez_bien-etre_2019,
    title = {Le bien-{\^e}tre des animaux d{\textquoteright}{\'e}levage : mythe ou r{\'e}alit{\'e} juridique ?},
    language = {fr},
    author = {Grimonprez, Beno{\^i}t},
    year = {2019},
    pages = {14},
    file = {Grimonprez - Le bien-{\^e}tre des animaux d{\textquoteright}{\'e}levage  mythe ou r{\'e}al.pdf:C\:\\Users\\Anne-Laure Mathy\\Zotero\\storage\\HFRB6MYT\\Grimonprez - Le bien-{\^e}tre des animaux d{\textquoteright}{\'e}levage  mythe ou r{\'e}al.pdf:application/pdf}}

@book{muller_a_2008,
    address = {Paris; Versailles},
    title = {{\'A} l'abattoir: travail et relations professionnelles face au risque sanitaire},
    isbn = {978-2-7351-1170-1 978-2-7592-0051-1},
    shorttitle = {{\'A} l'abattoir},
    language = {French},
    publisher = {{\'E}ditions de la Maison des sciences de l'homme ; {\'E}ditions Quae},
    author = {Muller, S{\'e}verin},
    year = {2008},
    note = {OCLC: 262718567}
}
```

Here is my LaTex file (part of it).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{natbib}

\definecolor{gris1}{gray}{0.4}

\title{yyyyyy}
\author{\textsc{kkkk}}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}


\mainmatter
\part{Revue de la littérature}
\chapter{chap1}

L'intérêt pour l'activité d'abattage a été étudié à plusieurs reprises en sciences sociales. Toutefois, la condition animale en elle-même y est très peu abordée, sans doute parce que les acteurs de terrain eux-mêmes la considère comme un non-sujet \citep{muller_a_2008}, mais aussi car l'objet d'une telle recherche est souvent accueilli, tout au plus. L'animal constitue donc un objet de travail doublement particulier, à la fois pour l'ouvrier, qui n'opère pas sur une chose inanimée mais également pour le chercheur, qui doit proposer une place nouvelle à l'animal dans son champ de recherche \citep{grimonprez_bien-etre_2019}.

\bibliographystyle{rusnat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear, open={(},close={)}}
\bibliography{bibli}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliographie}
\end{document}
\bibliographystyle{rusnat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear, open={(},close={)}}
\bibliography{bibli}
```

As I said, it worked successfully for previous references. Is there some information missing in the bibfile for this type of bibliography style?

The error I got from LaTex is: While executing - line 884 - rusnat.bst

Thank you in advance for your help :-)

Comment: Please provide a full (but minimal) example instead of a sniplet like this. Also note that `rusnat.bst` seems to have neem depreciated (aka not recommended anymore, see https://ctan.org/pkg/shipunov?lang=en)

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll update my example. Unfortunately, I could find a bibstyle suitable for my field...

Comment: Unrelated: have a look at the `tocbibind` package, if the bibliography is longer than a page, `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliographie}` will point to the wrong page. `tocbibind` fixes this.

Comment: If would of course be easier to help you if we knew which field you are in and what exactly you are writing. If it is something that is going to be published by a journal etc, then figure out what they recommend (don't try to invent something just be cause you like it, not not mean that the style matches the style they want). If it is something you publish, like a thesis or dissertation, then have a look at `biblatex` (a latex package). It is much more configurable than bibtex. But also requites you to use a different program than bibtex

Comment: `biblatex` uses `biber`, `bibtex` can be used with it, but is limited in what ti can do

Comment: Thanks but it's my thesis so it will me longer than a page :-D I am in sociology. So my basic rule is to have (Author, year) in the text and in the bibliography: no reference to citation in the text of this type [1], author full name, work, no link. I tried a biblatex option, without success. Should I open a new topic?

Comment: You should have mentioned this at the start, then it is much easier to help. You should use `biblatex` in this case. Remember that `biblatex` will need to to run `biber` not `bibtex`, did you instruct your editor to do that? Also see the `biblatex` manual. It can do **a lot**.

Comment: It might be an idea to do another question instead. One that is more specific to your problem. Remember to provide full but minimal example, so others know what they are dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

The `@article` type ***needs*** a journal name.

If you add the field `journal={\mbox{}}`, you get no error. But probably `@article` is the wrong type.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment, but here is a MWE of using `biblatex`. Note that this requites a recent latex installation because of the `[overwrite]` option to the `filecontents` env.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname-refs.bib}
@article{grimonprez_bien-etre_2019,
title = {Le bien-{\^e}tre des animaux d{\textquoteright}{\'e}levage : mythe ou r{\'e}alit{\'e} juridique ?},
language = {fr},
author = {Grimonprez, Beno{\^i}t},
year = {2019},
pages = {14},
volume={1},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[natbib,style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname-refs.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{blablabla}
my text \citep{grimonprez_bien-etre_2019}.

\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

[image]